# Android Studio: should I upgrade to Android embedding v2?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am actively learning dart/flutter, and using Android Studio. Just practicing to learn as much dart as possible. For now, I manly test my code by outputting into console. When I run the code, I get the warning message below (about upgrading to Android embedding v2), see picture. For now, I am not interested in developing apps for Android nor IOS, I am focusing mainly on web apps.

Is the warning below something I should consider upgrading now to Android embedding v2? Or can it wait until I decide to start testing Android apps?

The main reason why I didn't upgrade, it's because I read the Android embedding v2 upgrade instructions, and it requires to edit some files, and I don't want to risk messing up Android Studio, nor Dart, nor Flutter files. Also, this is the first time I use this IDE.

> Warning
> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> Your Flutter application is created using an older version of the Android
> embedding. It's being deprecated in favor of Android embedding v2. Follow the
> steps at

https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration

to migrate your project.

Comment: Possible because you're a new member you can't put image in your post, so upload it somewhere else and provide us the link so we can help you.

Comment: Thank you, I added a link to the image

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the error message, [don't upload code as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: About the message, a deprecation doesn't mean than your software will stop to work. But Android embedding v1 will be probably be unsupported in the future. Upgrading early will probably save you some time in the long run.

Comment: @A.L           Got it, will do, thanks.